# How to set the ethernet interface name in a Linux distribution?

Tags: linux, networking, udev

I'm developing yocto-base Linux distribution and I have to manage a WiFi-USB adapter.

When I insert the adapter in the USB connector, Linux kernel and `udev` add a wifi ethernet interface and set its name to `wlp0s21f0u8`.

I know that a new naming scheme has been introduced, to solve problems that arose from the old (eth0, wlan0) naming standards.
The name `wlp0s21f0u8` is a consequence of this new scheme.
Basically, the first two letter describe the type of interface: `wl` for wlan (wireless lan), `en` for ethernet.

When I plug in the WiFi-USB adapter the command `udevadm monitor`, that is available in my distribution, gives many logs that are listed below:

```
KERNEL[3538.552002] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8 (usb)
KERNEL[3538.554908] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[3538.628751] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/wakeup/wakeup39 (wakeup)
KERNEL[3538.629103] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/ieee80211/phy8 (ieee80211)
KERNEL[3538.629536] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/ieee80211/phy8/rfkill8 (rfkill)
KERNEL[3538.641836] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/net/wlan0 (net)
KERNEL[3538.642081] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/net/wlan0/queues/rx-0 (queues)
KERNEL[3538.642111] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/net/wlan0/queues/rx-1 (queues)
KERNEL[3538.642133] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/net/wlan0/queues/rx-2 (queues)
KERNEL[3538.642201] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/net/wlan0/queues/rx-3 (queues)
KERNEL[3538.642381] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/net/wlan0/queues/tx-0 (queues)
KERNEL[3538.642490] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/net/wlan0/queues/tx-1 (queues)
KERNEL[3538.642567] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/net/wlan0/queues/tx-2 (queues)
KERNEL[3538.642669] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/net/wlan0/queues/tx-3 (queues)
KERNEL[3538.649652] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[3538.649986] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8 (usb)
UDEV  [3538.652456] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8 (usb)
UDEV  [3538.654593] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [3538.657451] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/wakeup/wakeup39 (wakeup)
UDEV  [3538.660210] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/ieee80211/phy8 (ieee80211)
UDEV  [3538.661866] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/ieee80211/phy8/rfkill8 (rfkill)
KERNEL[3538.666927] move     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/net/wlp0s21f0u8 (net)
UDEV  [3538.684035] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/net/wlp0s21f0u8 (net)
UDEV  [3538.689310] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/net/wlan0/queues/rx-0 (queues)
UDEV  [3538.690951] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/net/wlan0/queues/rx-2 (queues)
UDEV  [3538.691687] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/net/wlan0/queues/rx-1 (queues)
UDEV  [3538.697841] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/net/wlan0/queues/tx-3 (queues)
UDEV  [3538.700271] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/net/wlan0/queues/tx-0 (queues)
UDEV  [3538.701113] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/net/wlan0/queues/tx-2 (queues)
UDEV  [3538.702787] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/net/wlan0/queues/tx-1 (queues)
UDEV  [3538.703428] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/net/wlan0/queues/rx-3 (queues)
UDEV  [3538.707760] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [3538.711545] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8 (usb)
UDEV  [3538.982603] move     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/net/wlp0s21f0u8 (net)
```

Among them I want to highlight the following that, in my opinion, are the most important:

```
...
KERNEL[3538.641836] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/net/wlan0 (net)
...
KERNEL[3538.666927] move     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/net/wlp0s21f0u8 (net)
...
UDEV  [3538.982603] move     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/net/wlp0s21f0u8 (net)
```

Previous logs show that kernel adds the interface `wlan0` and after its name is changed (**move**) to `wlp0s21f0u8`.

How can I rename the ethernet interface from `wlp0s21f0u8` to a name of my choice?

Please can someone help me to do that?

Thanks

Comment: At [this link](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) there are some info about this topic *Predictable Network Interface Names*. An [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/702161/why-is-my-interface-now-wlp2s0-instead-of-wlan0/723182#723182) is an other link useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want is to revert *all* interfaces to their original kernel names, the easiest way to do so is to boot with the `net.ifnames=0` kernel option – this tells udev to disable renaming entirely.

There are two ways to rename individual interfaces:

- Using a `.link` file in `/etc/systemd/network`. These are processed by udev rules (*not* by systemd-networkd) and this is actually the same mechanism that renames your interface to `wlp0s21f0u8` in the first place. See the [systemd.link(5)](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye-backports/udev/systemd.link.5.en.html) manual page for more details.

  If you want to revert the interface to the kernel name, use `NamePolicy=` with an empty value; if you want to use a custom name, specify it through `Name=`.

  ```
  [Match]
  <some match conditions>

  [Link]
  NamePolicy=
  Name=usbwifi
  ```

  Take a look at `/usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link` to see how the renaming feature gets enabled in the first place.

  All .link files are processed as part of udev's `80-net-setup-link.rules`. This being an embedded system, you could remove the rules file entirely (and the corresponding udev helper binary) if you don't use any .link file features.
- Using an udev rule. If you have an earlier rule that directly assigns `NAME=` (e.g. in a `70-custom-names.rules`), the later rule in that handles .link files will not override it.

  ```
  ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", KERNEL=="wlan0", NAME="usbwifi"
  ```

In both cases, avoid trying to rename something "back" to kernel-style `wlan#` names; if you want those, it's better to disable renaming entirely (e.g. by setting an empty NamePolicy) rather than try to undo it after the fact.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll study and try your tips and after I'll give a feedback.

Comment: Thank you @user1686 I have tested the second way and it works perfectly. I knew the rule but not the position of the file `70-custom-names.rules` and I put it in the folder `/etc/udev/rules.d` so it had not effect.

Comment: `/etc/udev/rules.d` is actually correct – it's the ordering/position respective to other rules that matters the most.

Comment: you are right again if I put the file `70-custom-names.rules` in `/etc/udev/rules.d` it works the same. So I suppose that when I tried before your answer I was using an erroneus rule.